# Como limpar o atributo value = " " do html:text

Tags: jsp

Bom dia pessoal, estou tentando limpar o atributo `value="teste"` da `tag` `html:text`, porém não estou conseguindo, o problema está qnd eu submeto o `form` com um campo vazio que é obrigatório ele faz o `redirect` para a mesma página mas com os valores salvo no campo que foi inserido antes, eu quero limpar esses dados que fica salvo no campo `value`. Segue abaixo a pagina renderizada. Estou usando `Struts 1.1` e `JSP`
[image: Dados no campo value para limpar]

Comment: Qual o comando que você usa pra redirecionar novamente para o formulário?

Comment: Boa tarde Flávio, eu consegui limpar o campo eu meio que forcei ele com o valor vazio, coloquei na tag html:text o atributo value="" e deu certo ele limpou o value, obrigado pela atenção.